# Get all authors with at least one post of 'custom post type'

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts, list-authors

How can i achive that?
I found [count_user_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts) and [get_users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users), but how would I merge them into the desired result? Do I really have to use a WP DB Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now `post_type` support is not currently available for `count_user_posts()`,

so put the below code in theme's functions.php file.

```
function count_user_posts_by_type( $userid, $post_type = 'post' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( $post_type, true, $userid );
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );
    return apply_filters( 'get_usernumposts', $count, $userid );
}
```

Now this function would take `user id` and `post_type` as parameter `post_type='post'` being the default and gets the count of post for that user for the concerned post_type

You can verify it by echoing the below where you need to check the post count by the user.

```
$user_posts = count_user_posts_by_type( 1, 'page' );
echo $user_posts; // This would return the post count for user id 1 and post_type page.
```

You can do the same for the custom post type. Now you need to get the user ids and pass through this function and display the name of the authors having 1 or more posts
or

You can add the below code where you want to display the list of users with one or more post

```
$blogusers = get_users();
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    if ( count_user_posts_by_type( $user->ID, 'post') ) {
         echo $user->user_nicename . '</br>';
    }
}
```

The above code lists all the users with one or more posts published of `post_type` **`post`**.

Answer (score 2):

Very old query but still there are no direct methods to get all authors with at least one post of 'custom post type'. [WP_User_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/) also does not support the post type. Using $wpdb will solve the issue.

Code:

```
$post_type = 'gutentor';/*Your Post type*/
global $wpdb;

$all_authors = $wpdb->get_results(
    "
    select
A.*, COUNT(*) as post_count
from
$wpdb->users A
inner join $wpdb->posts B
on A.ID = B.post_author
WHERE ( ( B.post_type = '$post_type' AND ( B.post_status = 'publish' OR B.post_status = 'private' ) ) )
GROUP BY A.ID
ORDER BY post_count DESC"
);

if ( $all_authors ) {
    foreach ( $all_authors as $author) {
        echo $author->display_name;
    }
}
```

You just need to assign `$post_type` with your post type.